# Функции JS (если аргумент передан и является функцией

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста. нужно переписать функцию "main" с таким вот условием.

Если аргумент "c" передан и он является функцией, то он выполняется после вызова функции sum, и в качестве входящего значение принимает результат работы функции sum.
Функция main должна возвращать результат функции аргумента c, если он есть, либо результат функции sum.

```
function main (a=2, b=3, c) { 
  
}

function sum (a, b) { 
    return a + b; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function main (a=2, b=3, c) {
  if(typeof(c) === 'function')
    return c(sum(a, b))
  else 
    return sum(a, b)
}

function sum (a, b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

console.log(main(10, 20, function(a){
  return a * 100000
}))
```